# How to get current html element(tag) in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, wysiwyg, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I am doing on WYSIWYG Html Editor using Java Program. I need When I click mouse on Paragraph element, It should be displays

tag in JOption dialog. Please advice me How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See for example this one http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html

In simple words you can get your `HTMLDocument` and get paragraph using `getParagraphElement()` method. Use `viewToModel()` method of `JEditorPane` to get caret offet for the clicked point.

Comment: I am a big fan of `viewToModel(...)` and `modelToView(...)` ever since I had heard of them, +1 for the answer :-)